# How to get online meeting attendance report ? / Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to get attendance intervals for every user that joined the meeting. I'm using Python request lib.

When I call API with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting_id}/attendanceReports`

this error occurs:

> "Application does not have permission to GetMeetingAttendanceReport
> online meeting on behalf of this user."

I successfully get results when I run the same query via Graph Explorer instead of Python request lib.

Added `OnlineMeetings.ReadAll` etc. permissions and granted admin consent doesn't help.

Comment: As you can get correct result by graph explorer, I'm afraid you need to check the azure ad app's api permission then, and try to generate an access token for test via that application. More details in my post below. If you feel it helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer by click the √ button beside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you successfully get results when using Graph Explorer, so it should be ok to get correct results through the same user and the same api permission. I'm afraid that you need to check the azure ad application api permission then.

Go to azure portal and find the azure ad application which you used in your python application. Go to the api permission blade to check if the delegate permission `OnlineMeetingArtifact.Read.All` mentioned in the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions) has been added to the permission list.

And if you wanna use application permission in your python project, you should add application permission here.

[image]

Then you are supposed to generate a correct access token via this application, whatever using client credential flow to generate an application token or auth flow to generate a user token.

[image]
[image]

And if you wanna test with http request first, you can set your request like my sample below to generate an application permission token then use it to call your api.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I double-checked azure app permissions, application already has both delegate and application permission. I can access email and calendar data with access token, but same token doesn't work with meeting attendance report.

In 'List meetingAttendanceReports' section of Graph API doc., there is an info like 'tenant administrators must create an application access policy'. Maybe this one helps but I need to figure it out that how to create an 'application access policy'.

Comment: Yes, the document said that if you use the application permission for generating the access token, you need to create an [app access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy), it also provides the tutorial, and did you meet any problem on it? By the way, if you used delegate permission to generate the access token, then it's not necessary for you to create the policy.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to create app access policy. I'll let you know if there's any progress. Thanks

Comment: Creating application access policy solved the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) solved the problem.

For those who encounter this situation, Connect Microsoft Teams via Windows Powershell ISE and follow the steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Try '/meetingAttendanceReport' instead of '/attendanceReports' in the url.

Comment: Both of them working on Graph Explorer, but not working on Python. Output is still permission error